# Using string concatenation within HTML img src in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, youtube

I am pulling videos from a playlist with the YouTube API v3. Each video JSON object has a videoId. I am trying to use the videoId to build the src attribute in the img element with Angular.

This is what I currently have:

```
<table id="playlistvideostable" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Thumbnail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="video in playlistvideos">
            <td>
                {{video.snippet.title}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{video.resourceId.videoId}}/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Video Thumbnail" class="img-responsive"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I concatenate the following strings in the src attribute of the img html element?

"http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video.resourceId.videoId + "/hqdefault.jpg"

Comment: I think ng-src instead of src should do the trick

Comment: isn't it working the way you shown above ? what happens ?

Comment: it supposed to work my friend. you do it fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use the ng-src directive instead of the original src attribute of the image element, the ng-src directive will recognize the string interpolation and apply it on the dom.

in your case -

```
  <img ng-src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{video.resourceId.videoId}}/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Video Thumbnail" class="img-responsive"/>
```

good luck.

Comment: Equivalent in Angular 2+: `[src]` (via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965667/whats-equivalent-to-ngsrc-in-the-newer-angular)