# Whats equivalent to ng-src in the newer Angular?

Tags: angular

I would like to implement img, with a src coming from JSON object.

In AngularJS, I could do:

```
<img ng-src="{{hash}}" alt="Description" />
```

Is there any equivalent to this in Angular 2+?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

AngularJS:

```
<img ng-src="{{movie.imageurl}}">
```

Angular 2+:

```
<img [src]="movie.imageurl">
```

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html)

---

Note that interpolation can achieve the same result:

```
<img src="{{vehicle.imageUrl}}">

<img [src]="vehicle.imageUrl">
```

There is no technical difference between these two statements for property binding, as long as you don't desire two-way binding.

> Interpolation is a convenient alternative for property binding in many
>   cases. In fact, Angular translates those interpolations into the
>   corresponding property bindings before rendering the view.
>   [source](https://hahoangv.wordpress.com/2016/05/30/display-data-in-angular-2/)

Comment: so, its not equivalent to ng-src, because ng-src avoids load image before ng-src has a value

Comment: As Sebastian told! It is not equal because elements like `video/audio` and few others should not have `attributes` with no value. `ng-src` is not equivalent to that `[src]`

Comment: To achieve the same outcome as ng-src, you'll need to add an `ngIf`, like so:
`<img *ngIf="vehicle?.imageUrl" [src]="vehicle.imageUrl">`

Comment: In Angular 15+ there is also ngSrc: https://angular.io/guide/image-directive

Answer (score 9):

It is a two-step process to achieve the same functionality of ng-src in your Angular application.

**First Step:**

In your HTML, use the new syntax:

`<img [src]="imageSrc">`

**Second Step:**

In your component/directive, initialize the value to be *empty*. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ag-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html'
})
export class SampleComponent {
   imageSrc = '';
}
```

Now, this would eliminate the `null` network call (empty call) due to the value not being set on to the element.

Answer (score 3):

It can also be written in interpolation form like:

```
<img src="{{movie.imageurl}}">
```

Comment: why not?? 54321

Answer (score -1):

```
<tr *ngFor="let post of posts | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 
       10, currentPage: p , totalItems: count  }">

   <td>
    <img src="{{post.youtubeVideoId}}">
   </td>

   <td>
     {{post.videoName}}
   </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't the recommended solution because it creates a failing request to: https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{post.youtubeVideoId}}/default.jpg.

Comment: Creates a failing request! Agreed.

Comment: I removed the part of the answer that broke the URL.