# iFrame Source with Angular Markup

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I want to use an Angular markup to pull a URL from a database and insert it into the source of an iframe. This is with what I'm presently working:

`<iframe ngSrc="{{post.url}}" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>`

When looking at Elements in Dev Tools, the URL string appears properly. However, the iframe does not render on the page.

**EDIT**: I found an example on Plunker that sort of works. The problem I'm having now is that it is assigning everything to the last url. Is there a way to differentiate them? This is my adaptation:

**app.js**

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sce', function($http, $scope, $sce) {

 this.allPosts = [];


 this.getAllPosts = () => {
   $http({
     url: "/posts", method: "get"
   }).then(response => {
     this.allPosts = response.data;
     for (let post of this.allPosts) {
       $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
         return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src)
       }
       $scope.track = {
         src: post.url
       }
     }
     console.log(this.allPosts);
   }, ex => {
     console.error(ex.data.err);
     this.error = ex.statusText;
   }).catch(err => this.error = "Server broke?");
 };
```

**html**

```
<div class="all_posts" ng-repeat="post in ctrl.allPosts | filter: searchBox" ng-click="ctrl.getOne(post)">  
  <div class="one_post">
    <div class="embedded_song">

      <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(track.src)}}" width="300" height="80" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
      {{ post.artist }} -
      <a href="/one_post/">{{ post.songTitle }}</a>
      <a href={{post.url}} target="blank">Listen here</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Submitted By -->
    <div class="post_content">
      submitted by: {{post.user.username}}<br>
      <!-- Optional Text Box? -->
    </div>

    <!-- Tags -->
    <div class="tag_area">
      <div class="post_tags" ng-repeat="tag in post.tag">
        <button class="post_tag">#{{tag}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I did this previously, and I think I ended up creating a directive that created the full iframe markup as a child element.

Answer (score 0):

`ngSrc` isn't a proper Angular (2+) directive, it is an AngularJS (1.x) directive. The propert formatting for Angular is:

```
<iframe [src]="post.url" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Where `[ ... ]` indicates a dynamic value, and `"post.url"` refers to the component variable.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965667/whats-equivalent-to-ngsrc-in-angular2) has several answer that are similar to your question, but refer to `img` instead of `iframe` explain the idea.

Comment: I tried using that, and no dice. No errors, either.

Comment: what is console.log value of post.url?

Comment: Also, have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037760/how-to-set-iframe-src-in-angular-2-without-causing-unsafe-value-exception

Comment: That is waaaaaaay above my skill level. I'm posting an update. I appreciate your assistance thus far.

Comment: You're mixing up AngularJS with Angular a whole lot there man. If you google, be sure to include `-angularjs` in your search

Comment: Yeah, I've honestly been attempting to cobble together various solutions I've found on the internet.